# Using EntityManager with Table API

Tags: java, database, hibernate, api, entitymanager

I'm working on a Java webapplication and want to access the database (PostgreSQL) via an database API for security reasons. The API of the database is built by database functions.

How can I call the API functions with an EntityManager? I figured out a way with native queries, but I think then there is not much left of ORM. Is there a way for example to lead the entityManager.persist() method to one of the database functions?

Comment: So basically, you want `em.persist(...)` to invoke your own custom database function?

Comment: Yes, so is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good idea. The entire point of JPA is to standardize the way the database is accessed and mapped to the Object layer. If you want to use native DB functions then you should use JDBC, possibly via SpringJDBCTemplate or some other tool that eases some of the pain. If you really feel like punishing yourself though, you could always create your own implementation of EntityManager and use that in your classes.

Comment: But the underlying purpose should be, that the application will access the database only via a non-privileged db-user, which calls the API functions. So to use such a mechanism I shouldn't go with EntityManager? Is there an alternative approach?

Comment: If there is a business or technical lead directive that you need to use these API functions, then yea, you are painted into a corner. Make sure whoever gave you that restriction knows that they are limiting your technical options by mandating this. Using JDBC is probably your best bet.